# ping 8.8.8.8 not working using static ip in CentOS 7.0

Tags: linux, centos, static-ip, redhat-enterprise-linux

Can someone please help me in fixing the destination unreachable error when I execute ping `8.8.8.8` in CentOS 7?

It was working fine when the network type is DHCP. Could you please help me. I am new to Linux. Here are the details.

**OS:** CentOS 7

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPADDR=192.168.1.23
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
NAME=Test
UUID=f7cc64f5-1b39-448f-9282-53dde8d5d85f
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:0C:29:EB:E4:27
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Contents of `resolve.conf`:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

etc-sysconfig-network:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=puppet.test
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

**UPDATE:** I am getting the below output for gateway and nslookup

```
[root@puppet ~]# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.129 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.129 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3012ms
pipe 2
[root@puppet ~]# ping ^C
[root@puppet ~]# nslookup www.purple.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe8e:6900  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:8e:69:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 126  bytes 17135 (16.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 403  bytes 31235 (30.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 841  bytes 79599 (77.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 841  bytes 79599 (77.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: can you ping the gateway? does NSLookup resolve `nslookup www.purple.com 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: Also, what settings did it get via DHCP (i.e. the one that worked)?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the interface isn't up? What feedback does ping give you when you try it? Destination unreachable?

By the way the DNS file's name should be resolv.conf , not resolv**e**.conf. If you've created it yourself maybe that's the problem?

Comment: well, if you can't ping the gateway, then your network is completely inaccessible, so somthing basic has gone awry. I notice that your IP appears to be .129 in your ping but your config above specifies .23, which implies that the config is not being used for some reason. The MAC address is also different, so fix that ASAP. it may be the issue.

Comment: you can ping the host by its own IP, right? Do you have `ethtool` installed? what do you get from `ethtool ens33`? Does it show "Link detected: yes"?

Comment: well, your nic looks fine, as does your IP configuration. are you absolutely certian that the gateway is at 192.168.1.1? some routers prefer the end of a range, so perhaps 192.168.1.254? you said that it worked when you used DHCP. could you reconfigure to use DHCP, and reboot? then run `ipconfig -a`, `route`, and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to see what is different?

Answer (score 1):

From your feedback it appears as if the interface is up, so that's not the problem?

If you've created resolve.conf yourself and it isn't just a typo here, then maybe the problem is that the correct name for it is **resolv.conf**?
You can rename it like this from a terminal:

> cd /etc
>   mv resolve.conf resolv.conf

and then try pinging again.

Otherwise try removing the gateway as a DNS server, and replace the contents of resolv.conf with:

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>   nameserver 8.8.4.4

?

Answer (score -1):

I changed my VM settings from NAT to Bridged Network, it started working. Thanks for all your help.

```
[root@puppet ~]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=24.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=18.8 ms
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify that you're talking about a virtual host and specifically vmware from the start, directly in the text and/or via  the tags. I'm not totally sure it was exactly vmware now, though, as you seem to've deleted your answer which had a lot of the comments trying to solve your problem, which is also where you told us it was a VM after a while.